# Receiving 'Expected Declaration' when setting the image of a UIButton with <uibutton>.setImage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

Heres the code, and for some reason `Expected Declaration` keeps on showing up beside it. Also [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837371/how-to-change-uibutton-image-in-swift) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027618/uibutton-setimage-not-working) didn't seem to work for me.

```
import UIKit

class SpeechBubble: UIView {
    let uButton  = UIButton(type: .custom)
    let uImage = UIImage (named: "Upvote")
    uButton.setImage(uImage, for: .normal)
}
```

Upvote is an image inside Assets.xcassets that is listed as universal and has 1x, 2x and 3x options

Comment: Put your code in a function.

Comment: @rmaddy >:( 
Well that worked. Any more advice?

Comment: @rmaddy What is it a duplicate of, I posted 2 links of similar questions that don't discuss putting it in a function, and I couldn't find any answers that discussed putting it in a function